# Cannot get an messagebox after calculation

Tags: c#, methods, parameters

So I made a short method with parameters to calculate whatever is being typed in the txtBoxes.

```
string Calculate(string number1, string number2)
{
  number1 = txtNumber1.Text;
  number2 = txtNumber2.Text;
  string sum = number1 + number2;

  return sum;
}
```

And here I tried to messageBox it but it shows an error at Calculate...

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show(Calculate().ToString);
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: it's probably doing this: `3 + 4 = 34` which is the error he's talking about

Comment: as @Andy said it it shows 34 instead of 7

Comment: do this: `string sum = (Convert.ToInt(number1) + Convert.ToInt(number2)).ToString();`

Comment: How are you calling `Calculate()` without passing the two parameters this method wants? Shouldn't you call it as, e.g., `Calculate(txtNumber1.Text, txtNumber2.Text)`? Why are you converting to string the return value when it's already a string? Did you mean to pass two numeric values to this method instead, then get back the value of the operation as a numeric value? Homework?

Comment: You are not Calculating numbers. That&#39;s concatenation of string. You get text from texboxes and convert/parse it to integer , double etc.. do Calculation then return the result as string. Also you require parameters. I don't know how you debugged your program without it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are not **calculating** two integers, instead, you are **concatenating** those two strings. So you need to convert those string from textboxes into an integer to do the calculations

You should do this..

```
int Calculate(int number1, int number2)
{
  number1 = int.Parse(txtNumber1.Text);
  number2 = int.Parse(txtNumber2.Text);
  int sum = number1 + number2;

  return sum;
}
```